# Code not giving expected result

Tags: angularjs

When I was running my code it shows undefined with text box which I don't want to see. So I how I can remove  that undefined word?

```js
$scope.click1=function(){
      $scope.clicked1=!$scope.clicked1;
      $scope.val1=$scope.value1;
      document.getElementById("t2").innerHTML=$scope.val1;
  }
```

```html
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" id="t2" ng-click="click1()">Venue</span>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="write some details" ng-show="clicked1" ng-model="value1">
```

Comment: Can we see your entire controller? It seems something other than what we can see may be the cause (have you injected $scope for example?).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a variable called val1 and another value1.
Normal ?
Be sure that you're using the same value in each code (.js and .html)